# Limits with $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume $\lim_{x \to a^{-}} f(x) < \lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$. Prove that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x < a < y$, $|x-a| < \delta$, and $|y-a| < \delta$, then $f(x) < f(y)$.

It seems hard to utilize the left and right limit definitions. The function is not continuous at $a$ also. But could we say $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad -\delta < x-a \quad \implies \quad f(x) < f(y)?$$